# mypy type hint for function that returns both None and string

Tags: python, mypy

I have two functions like this. How would I type hint `func()` such that mypy does not raise an error?

Right now it says

```
test.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "str | None"; expected "Sized"  [arg-type]
```

```py
from typing import Optional

path = "path"

def func(path: str) -> Optional[str]:
    s = "foo"
    if True:
        return s
    return None

def func2() -> None:
    if func(path) is not None:
        if len(func(path)) > 0:
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("No")
```

I tried `Optional[str]` and `Union` but neither seems to work.

Comment: If the function truly is `if True:`, then just make the return type `str`. Mypy is smart enough to understand what unreachable code looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mypy can't know that both invocations of `func` will yield the same result. It therefor can't know that if `func(path) is not None` the first time, the second time `func(path)` is called in `len(func(path))` the return value being `None` is not possible. mypy is correct in this conservative assumption.

You can bind the return value to a variable, which allows mypy to reason about the possible types *of that variable* across the type-narrowing `if`.

```
def func2() -> None:
    foo = func(path)
    # `foo` can only be `None` or a `str`; but `foo` in `len(foo)` can't be None.
    if foo is not None and len(foo) > 0:
        print("Yes")
        return
    print("No")
```

As a side-note: The expression `foo is not None and len(foo) > 0` can be shortened to just `foo`. Both `None` and the empty string evaluate false-ish.